# Handling both a ConnectionError and a status code error

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using `requests` to get some data from a server, which is done in a while loop. However, every now and then, one of two errors occur. The first is that the `status_code` of the return from the request is not equal to 200, and this prints out an error message. The second is that a `ConnectionError` exception is raised.

If I receive either error, I want to keep attempting to get the data. However, I'm not sure how to do this for both types of error.

I know how to handle the `ConnectionError` exception, for example:

```
def get_data(self, path):
    # Keep trying until the connection attempt is successful
    while True:
        # Attempt a request
        try:
            request_return = requests.get(path, timeout=30)
            break
        # Handle a connection error
        except ConnectionError as e:
            pass
# Return the data
return request_return.json()
```

But how can I also handle the `status_code` in a similar manner? Is it something to do with the `raise_for_status(`) method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could just adjust your try/except to look like this:

```
try:
    request_return = requests.get(path, timeout=30)
    if request_return.status_code == 200:
        break
except ConnectionError as e:
    pass
```

If you prefer, you can use `request_return.status_code == requests.codes.ok` as well.

If you're set on handling the request as an exception (for whatever reason), `raise_for_status()` returns an [HTTPError](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/models/#Response.raise_for_status), so you can amend your try/except like this:

```
try:
    request_return = requests.get(path, timeout=30)
    request_return.raise_for_status()
    break
except ConnectionError as e:
    pass
except HTTPError as e:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test the status code and leave the loop only on a 200 like:

#### Code:

```
if request_return.status_code == 200:
    break
```

#### Probably should limit the number of retries:

```
import requests

def get_data(path):
    # Keep trying until the connection attempt is successful
    retries = 5
    while retries > 0:
        # Attempt a request
        try:
            request_return = requests.get(path, timeout=3)
            if request_return.status_code == 200:
                break
        # Handle a connection error
        except ConnectionError as e:
            pass
        retries -= 1

    if retries == 0:
        """ raise an error here """

    # Return the data
    return request_return.json()

get_data('https://stackoverflow.com/rep')
```